# Setting private property of class via array notation?

Tags: javascript

Lets say you have a class like this:

```
class ExampleClass {

    #foo;
    constructor(){

        let VarName = 'foo';
        let VarNamePrefixed = '#foo';

        this[#VarName] = 'Bar'; // won't work, syntax error.
        this[VarNamePrefixed] = 'Bar'; // Won't work, escapes into a string.

    }

}
```

Is there a nice way to set private (#foo) variables using the array notation?

Comment: You could try: `this[eval(VarNamePrefixed)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use square brackets for this, the closest I can think of is using eval, which wouldn't be wise (in any case I don't really see the point, as you'll need to define the private property outside the constructor and not even eval will work there).

```js
class ExampleClass {

  #foo
  constructor(){
    let VarNamePrefixed = '#foo'

    eval("this." + VarNamePrefixed + ' = "Bar"')

    console.log(this.#foo)
  }
}

var foo = new ExampleClass
```

Comment: Hm, That works I Suppose.
Not a great solution but if there is no alternative...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `[]` syntax to access private fields.

See the [private syntax FAQ](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/master/PRIVATE_SYNTAX_FAQ.md#why-doesnt-thisx-access-the-private-field-named-x-given-that-thisx-does).

> 1. This would complicate property access semantics.
> 2. Dynamic access to private fields is contrary to the notion of 'private'.